# Toyota Axio 2007 Melted Dashboard

Tags: toyota, corolla, dashboard

I have Toyota Corolla Axio 2007 (Japan Domestic Model -  DBA NZE141) and the dashboard has the melting issue. I have several places here that repairs the dashboard by removing the existing melted layer and applying it again using the machine. Some people say that if I do that the Air bags wont come out in an accident. I want to know, if there is anyone out there, who has had the same issue and if anyone can recommend if it is okay to go for repair, rather than buying and installing a new dashboard? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! By "melting issue" are you referring to when the plastic on the dash gets all sticky?

Comment: As long as you have a gap around where the airbag deploys shouldn’t it be good? As long as the wiring etc is still in tact

Comment: Toyota has a known issue regarding melting dashboards of cars from around 2007, they even did a recall, http://www.toyotaproblems.com/trends/melting-dashboard/ , I would recommend you to contact your seller and see if you can get a replacement for free